# How do I setup Twitter OAuth on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, coffeescript, twitter-oauth

I am trying to authenticate to Twitter using the access token and secret from my account, and I don't know how to do what I thought I was doing. I am using node-oauth, but I am open to other solutions.

PS: This is an app w/o a frontend. It is pretty much a twitter bot (don't worry, not a spammer). What I need to be able to do is access the Streaming API, which I need to POST after authenticating. IDK how to use basic auth, but if that would be easier, let me know.

Comment: I'd recommend [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth). The examples work

Answer (score 0):

try looking at [this code](https://gist.github.com/555607)